# Unexpected Padding Behaviour - Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple nav element that is going to sit with my footer on a page.

When I add padding to this item, the element shrinks by the amount of the stated padding.

Normally when you adding padding to an element it doesn't shrink the actual element. I understand that `box-sizing: border-box` makes sure the padding is included in the total width, but I've made the width 100% of the parent.

The same issue hasn't happened with the header or footer elements.

Really very confused here.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/opZjEr

```css
/* NAV ABOVE FOOTER */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#footer-nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul#footer-nav-items {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background: yellow;
}

ul#footer-nav-items li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 1.44rem;
}
```

```html
<nav id="footer-nav">
  <ul id="footer-nav-items">
    <li class="footer-menu-item">Home</li>
    <li class="footer-menu-item">Privacy / Terms</li>
    <li class="footer-menu-item">Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nav element is not shrinking with your padding. It remains at `width: 100%`.

Maybe you're judging the width of the nav element based on the yellow background color.

Just keep in mind that the yellow background is applied to the `ul` not the `nav` element.